# python (built-in)json de/serilazation with nested custom types

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, serialization

I don't have much experience with json module in python2 (2.7). Now I am facing a problem: How to serialize a custom object to json and later de-serialize it back.

I have this object hierarchy as example:

```
class Company(object):
    def __init__(self, company_id):
        self.company_id = company_id
        self.name = ''
        # other 10 attributes with simple type
        ...
        self.departments = [] #list of Dept objects

class Dept(object):
    def __init__(self, dept_id):
        self.dept_id = dept_id
        self.name = ''
        # other 10 attributes with simple type
        ...
        self.persons = [] #list of Person objs


class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, per_id):
        self.per_id = per_id
        self.name = ''
        # other 10 attributes with simple type
        ...
        self.skills = [] #list of Skill objs

class Skill(object):
    def __init__(self, skill_id):
        self.skill_id = skill_id
        self.name = ''
        # other 10 attributes with simple type
        ...
        self.foos = [] #list of Foo objs

class Foo(object):
    .....
```

Now say I have got an object from `Company`, with all attributes and lists from nested object filled. I want to save the object into a json file. And later load it back, so that those nested objects (`departments, persons, skills`) are loaded as well.

I have read pydoc, knew that the json de/encoding is dict based.  I can now do the serialization with this:

```
    json.dump(company_obj, jsonfile, default = lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

but it is hard to get it back to `Company` later.

I thought this problem would be common thing. I do searched here at SO and google, didn't find helpful information.

What is the proper way in this case to do json serialization and de-serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are custom encoders and decoders. These are documented here : http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

A working solution is to add the qualified class name to the dict while encoding and use it to create an instance of the right class when decoding.

Comment: I think I got what you meant. I created two functions, one adds `__class__` and `__module__` to the dict for encoding. the other one, first does `__import__`, then checks the `__class__` for which type and instantiate the right object with corresponding attributes. I used the two function as `default=`(encoding) and `object_hook=`(decoding). so far it works... I thought it would be easier to handle json with py. I hope I did it in right.